How access in java Access to NetworkRegistrationInfo getNrState()
I have this fuction. But i get error on this line:|
int nrState = regInfo.getNrState();

Message:

Cannot resolve method 'getNrState' in 'NetworkRegistrationInfo

Can someone where i make mistake? Or I should do this in different way?
ServiceState serviceState = telephonyManager.getServiceState();
if (serviceState != null) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        for (NetworkRegistrationInfo regInfo : serviceState.getNetworkRegistrationInfoList()) {
            if (regInfo.getAccessNetworkTechnology() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_NR) {
                int nrState = regInfo.getNrState(); // 
                switch (nrState) {
                    case NetworkRegistrationInfo.NR_STATE_NONE:
                        return "Not in NR state";
                    case NetworkRegistrationInfo.NR_STATE_RESTRICTED:
                        return "Restricted NR state";
                    case NetworkRegistrationInfo.NR_STATE_NOT_RESTRICTED:
                        return "Non-restricted NR state";
                    case NetworkRegistrationInfo.NR_STATE_CONNECTED:
                        return "Connected to 5G NR";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I need access to getNrState() for each sim card.
